# Model locomotive circuit review

Tags: arduino-nano

I am building a model scale locomotive and therefore use Arduino for the DC motor, smoke generator, sound and lights. Can you help me with reviewing the circuit?

Power comes from rechargeable batteries (9.6V). This will supply the buck converter and the motor shield. Rest of circuit runs on 5V. A few MOSFETS regulate power for LEDs and smoke generator. MOSFET is overkill for this scale I know now. The locomotive has two parts: locomotive itself and the tender where the batteries and boards are put in. I just need to connect 5 cables for it to work.

Can you help reviewing if there are any errors / electrical shorts possibilities. Please don't add unnecessary complexity.

[image: https://i.postimg.cc/tRP78kpY/Locomotive-circuit.png]

Comment: a schematic diagram is almost always clearer than a wiring diagram ... a quick glance reveals a couple of unknowns ... are mosfet connections correct? ... can DFplayer handle a 4 ohm speaker?

Comment: Shouldn't the red and white LEDs swap when the direction changes? (Three white on the front, 1 red at the back) This is not possible with this design.

Comment: 1) I think you also need to connect 5V to the Vcc pin of the motor driver board. 2) I'd connect the LED to 5V. That way their brightness will remain constant, even when the battery voltage drops due to discharge. This will also run them more effeciently; giving you better battery life. 3) I'd add resistor to the base of the mosfets. 4) You may need to run the leds at less than 20mA, as they might be too bright.